# Copy stylesheet content to clipboard

Tags: jquery, css, copy, stylesheet, liquid

Hi mighty Wizards of the web,

### Question:

Is it possible to **copy the contents of a specifiy stylesheet** to the users clipboard?

### Example:

1. The User clicks on a "copy to clipboard" button.
2. The contents of the forms.css is copied to his clipboard.
3. The User can paste those content in hier own project.

### Possible Approaches:

1. Use a plugin: The [copycss plugin](https://github.com/moagrius/copycss) seems to be coming close to what I need, but copies only the css of specified DOM elements. I would need the css-code of a whole stylesheet. Example: Everything that is related to form elements (copied from the forms.css)
2. Copy from the DOM: Another approach would be to insert the stylesheets content into a hidden textfield and copy it from there via jQuery. But I'm not sure if its possible to somehow grab the content and insert it into the DOM.

**Any Ideas?**

I'm grateful for **any push in the right direction**.

All the best! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a stylesheet as a string you can use `document.styleSheets`, and do something like this

```
var styleSheet  = document.styleSheets[0],
    styleString = $.map(styleSheet.rules, function(rule) {
        return 'cssText' in rule ? rule.cssText : '';
}).join("\n");
```

note that `document.styleSheets` is a collection, so `[0]` gets the first stylesheet in the page, `[1]` gets the second etc.

As for saving to the clipboard, that can be rather complicated, the prefered way is to use a prompt, something like this

```
window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", styleString);
```

telling the user to manually copy the string.

If you want a cross browser way to use a button instead, you would have to use flash, and there are plugins for this, [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard) is most commonly used, but there's also [Clippy](https://github.com/mojombo/clippy), which is a little easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

See [400212](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) for an overview of methods for copying data to clipboard.

As for getting the CSS;

```
var styles = document.styleSheets[0].href;
$.get(styles, function(data) {
  console.log(data); // call the clipboard copy function on data here
});
```